# Different increment on a for loop depending on a boolean

Tags: java, for-loop, increment, termination, decrement

How can i select the increment on a for loop depending on a boolean,i am trying to do something like this:

```
    for (int y = iniY; isdown? (y >= endY): (y <= iniY+dy) ; isdown? --y:y++);
```

the for loop accepts the termination but not the increment...

The working code i currently have is something like this:

```
    if(isdown)
        for (int y = iniY; y >= endY; --y) {
            code lines...
        }
    else
        for (int y = iniY; y <= iniY+dy; ++y) {
            code lines...
        }
```

the code can not be extracted to a new method because it works on many variables...

Comment: Why its so complicated, next programmer will take a look and will waste time to understand and , sure, to debug. I don't see any problem in second example but since Java is no bash script ...

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: @Aaron How would you debug this row of code: `for (int y = iniY; isdown? (y >= endY): (y <= iniY+dy) ; isdown? --y:y++);`

Comment: @MaximShoustin I wouldn't. I'd use the current code instead unless there's something wrong with it.

Comment: @Aaron, no, nothing wrong, just design

Comment: the current code has duplicated code but is working

Comment: @Anjes In that case I'd say that there is a big smell in your code. I'd concentrate on refactoring your code, rather than trying to hack this particular bit to make it work. If the code relies on to many variables to squirt into an extracted method, then something seems wrong in the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to minitech's solution but without a branch inside the loop.

```
int end = isdown ? iniY - endY : dy;
int direction = isdown ? -1 : +1;

for(int i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
    int y = iniY + direction * i;
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(initialization;condition; increment/decrement){}
```

If `condition` part of `for` loop is failed, then `increment` part will not work.

Comment: i dont get it, do you mean like this:for (int y = iniY; isdown? (y >= endY): (y <= iniY+dy) ;--y/y++);

Answer (score 0):

I’d do this:

```
int end = isdown ? iniY - endY : dy;

for(int i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
    int y = isdown ? iniY - i : iniY + i;
    …
}
```

That is to say, figure out the difference and loop over that. It’s easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that there is a big smell in your code. I'd concentrate on refactoring your code, rather than trying to hack this particular bit to make it work. If the code relies on to many variables to squirt into an extracted method, then something seems wrong in the design.